# VueApollo CORS request fails

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, vue-apollo

i'm facing a problem trying to make a request to API with address different against client.

client app lives at `http://localhost:8080`
server app lives at `http://localhost:4000`

in `main.js` i'm creating apollo client

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/v1/graphql',
})

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})
```

and feed the `apolloProvider` variable to Vue.

in component code that's calling API endpoint is looking like this

```
<template>
  <div>{{ categories }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  apollo: {
    categories: gql`query {
      categories {
        name
        _id
      }
    }`
  }
}
</script>
```

my GraphQL server that should accept the query from VueApollo is looking like this

```
// apollo
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } = require('apollo-server')

const typeDefs = require('./schema')
const resolvers = require('./resolvers')

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    methods: 'POST',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    preflightContinue: false,
  },
})

server.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` app running at ${url}`)
})
```

in Chrome browser requests from VueApollo accepted and response returned appropriately, but in FireFox i'm getting a CORS errors like this

[image]

am i missing anything guys? please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure what was wrong, but while i was trying to find out a solution i've noticed that my vue-cli module out of date. for me it was 3.1.1. so i updated vue cli to 4.5.9 and it got worked.